# A problem about the meaning of a big italic π (meeting in Markov Chain Invariant Distribution)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I'm self-studying the UCB - CS126 (Probability theory), and I meet the big italic π in the picture below.
The Chapter is 5.10, which tells the network of queues and product-form Networks.
[Picture Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOkw6.png)
I know that the π(x) of a Markov Chain should be a possibility vector which satisfies πA=π, but what does the big Pie means?
Does it mean "Multiply" like most big Pie, or (I guess) the concatenation of sets, or others?
Thanks you if you can answer me.

Comment: It means multiply.

Comment: thanks, maybe I should think the equation again.